# How to use binding values from text drop down lists to perform calculations?

Tags: javascript, livecycle-designer

I am trying to figure out how to have a couple of drown down text lists that return a numerical value depending on the choice made. Then those choices (the binding values) are multiplied to generate an answer.

For example, right now I have two probability text fields, Go% and Get% which have choices such as 0% Canceled, 10% Indefinite Hold, and so on. If someone chooses 10% indefinite hold, I want the binding value of .10 to be part of a formula that calculates the value go% * get%.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your value set on the Object > Binding tab. Then this js should work.

```
var product = ddList1.rawValue * ddList2.rawValue;
```

I tested this on a form from scratch to verify. The rawValue of a drop down list is the bound value of the selected item.